# Error handler not being invoked for sftp outbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to be able to catch any exceptions that are thrown by the `int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter` while uploading files to the sftp server. I was expecting that by simply specifying `int:service-activator` to use `errorChannel` as input I will be able to capture any and all exceptions thrown by my sftp integration flow. That doesn't seem to be the case. I am simulating an exception by trying to write to a path that I don't have access to and the exception is thrown but not passed on to the service activator.

```
<int:channel id="input" />

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="input"
    remote-directory-expression="headers['remote_dir']"
    remote-filename-generator-expression="headers['remote_file_name']" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel">
    <bean
        class="...ErrorHandler" />
</int:service-activator>
```

---

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [String payload -> sftp.txt]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/sftp.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 3: Permission denied
```

Also I have noticed that some people are using `sftp:request-handler-advice-chain` to handle errors. Is that a more appopriate (and functional) way of dealing with sftp errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show what starts your flow. i.e. what is publishing to `input`, most often this is a gateway of some kind.

Typically, you would put an `error-channel` on that component and handle exceptions in the error flow there - the message is an `ErrorMessage` with `cause` and `failedMessage` properties.

Comment: Thanks - that did it. Using a gateway and specifying an error channel on it

Comment: Is it possible to not use a gateway and simply push a message into a direct channel linked with an sftp-outputback-adapter and still be able catch any exceptions.

Comment: The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is for you then: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Okay that works good but one more question on that - The original message that goes into sftp-gateway, in my case, is a byte[] with a header that indicates the remote_file_name. These headers are not included in the `AdviceMessage` passed to the successChannel. Is there a way to keep the headers from original mesage going into sftp-gateway to the advice message

Comment: never mind - `inputMessage` property answered my question. Thanks again

Comment: So the failure messages do get conveyed to the failure channel but an exception is still thrown. Is that the intended behavior. Do I need to set `trapException` to true to just deliver the failure message along with exception and do my business logic instead of letting the exception be thrown

Comment: Yes, `trapException` will suppress the exception propagation.